# Findig the 2nd last item in the list, please explain this solution

Tags: list, scala, recursion, functional-programming, pattern-matching

```
// But pattern matching also makes it easy.
  def penultimateRecursive[A](ls: List[A]): A = ls match {
    case h :: _ :: Nil => h
    case _ :: tail     => penultimateRecursive(tail)
    case _             => throw new NoSuchElementException
  }
```

Can someone comment what this is doing line by line?

Is the [A] a generic like in c# we would do ?

h doesn't seem to be defined?

I think the major part of the algo is the recursive call:

```
case _ :: tail     => penultimateRecursive(tail)
```

There doesnt' seem to be a check for 2 items in the list, and then taking the 1st item to get the 2nd last, confused!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The keys to understanding the pattern match are to realize that `x :: y` will *only* match a list with a single item `x` followed by the rest of the list `y` (which could be just `Nil`, or could be many elements), and that `_` means "there needs to be something here, but we won't bother naming it".  (And that the matches occur in order, and that lists end with `Nil`.)

You're correct that `[A]` is a generic type.

So, the first line:

```
case h :: _ :: Nil => h
```

says, if our list looks like (conceptually) `Node(h) -> Node(whatever) -> Nil`, then we return `h`.  This is exactly a two-element list with the first item selected.  Note that `Nil` does *not* match any arbitrary tail of the list; it matches only the end-of-list item `Nil`.  This is because of a rule that Scala uses to distinguish the two: lower case variables are treated as wildcards that are to have the appropriate value filled in, while upper case variables are treated as constants to match.  (If you must match a lower-case name, you can if surround it by backticks.)

Okay, now suppose it's not a two-element list.  Then if it's not empty, it will match

```
case _ :: tail => penultimateRecursive(tail)
```

so if we haven't got a two-element list, we throw away the first item and try again.  Finally, if we somehow never ended up with a two-element list, we get to

```
case _ => throw new NoSuchElementException
```

and we're done.  (This could also be `case Nil`, actually, since this is the only possibility that doesn't match the other two entries.)

Comment: `x :: y` will match `x` followed by *any list* `y`, i.e. *zero or more* elements.

Comment: @larsmans - That's what I meant, but the whole `Nil` is a item thing is non-obvious (or, depending on your perspective, incorrect).  I'll fix my wording.

Comment: You might make it clearer that lower case identifiers in a pattern match are like `val` declarations, in that these identifiers are created in the scope of that match and assigned values extracted from the match. Be sure of the _lowercase_ part, and contrast it with uppercase `Nil`, which is compared to.

Comment: where can I find the operator :: in the language reference?

Comment: List is abstract, and has two subclasses: "::" and Nil. Here's the documentation for the former: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

Comment: @Rex Kerr: Nil is not an item, afaik, but just represents an empty list. What I am trying to say is that, if you do `x :: y` on a single-element list, the single element is assigned to `x`, and `y` now is an empty list, not "no item".

Comment: @x3ro - `Nil` is an object, so in that sense it is an item.  It is the object that represents the end of the list (i.e. no more items in the list), so in that sense it is not an item.  This is why I changed the wording in my answer (prompted by larsmans).

Answer (score 4):

`A` is a type variable, meaning the function is defined generically for any type `A`.

`h` is bound by the pattern matching: the first `case` states, if there are exactly two elements, then call the first `h` and return it.

> There doesnt' seem to be a check for 2 items in the list

There is: `h :: _ :: Nil` means "an element `h`, followed by any element, followed by no more elements." `Nil` isn't an element, it's the end of the list.

> and then taking the 1st item to get the 2nd last

Taking the first *of a two-element list* means taking the penultimate. If the list has fewer or more elements than two, the other two cases apply.

Answer (score 3):

larsmans and Rex have covered your questions, but see Chapter 9 for more details on '::' http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The first line means that any list element h will be returned if h is followed by another one and a Nil pointer (at the end of the list). The actual element following to h is not important, that's why you use _ to specify that there is an element but you don't care about its value.

If the first case does not match, the second case will invoke recursion if the list has a head element and a tail of at least one element.

Lastly you bail out on lists consisting only a single element. Once again, you don't have to care about the actual value of the elements value.